addEventListener i removeEventListener on menu when resize window
What am I doing wrong? When menu opened in mobile version (< 768 px), first click should open the submenu and second click should get the parent URL (it works). After increasing the window width to >= 768 px, the submenu should show on hover over the parent, and the parent  tag should redirect to the URL on first click (this doesn't work).
Please help me reorganize window.addEventListener('resize', function(){ ... }); Because addEventListener and removeEventListener do not work properly.
Why is the event triggering the prevFirstClick (mobile first) function not removed when the screen is enlarged to >= 768 px?
Why is the event triggering the prevFirstClick (desktop first) function not added when the screen is reduced to < 768 px?
Can someone guide me? I made hundreds of different combinations but I couldn't achieve the desired effect.


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // prevent defalt behavior on parent <a> tags - first click open submenu, second click opend href URL
  let static_window_width = window.innerWidth;
  const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children');

  function prevFirstClick() {
    menuItems.forEach(item => {

      const preventListener = function(event) {
        let isOpen = item.getAttribute('aria-expanded');

        if (isOpen == 'false') {
          item.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');

          if (event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
          } else {
            event.returnValue = false;
          }
        }
      }
      item.addEventListener('click', preventListener);
    }); // koniec pętli foreach.
  };

  // fires event whent mobile firts

  if (static_window_width < 768) {
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', prevFirstClick);
  }

  // prevent default behavior on parent <a> tag whent first desktop and user deside to resize to mobile and vice versa remove prevent default from <a> tag when mobile first and then resize to desktop.

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

    const menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-item-has-children');
    let dynamic_window_width = this.innerWidth;

    if (dynamic_window_width < 768) {
      window.addEventListener('click', prevFirstClick);
    } else {
      window.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', prevFirstClick, true);

      menuItems.forEach(item => {
        let isOpen = item.getAttribute('aria-expanded');

        if (isOpen == 'true') {
          // first click on parent opens submenu
          item.setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'false');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
li[aria-expanded="false"] .submenu {
  display: none;
}

li[aria-expanded="true"] .submenu {
  display: zblock;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  ul.menu>li:hover .submenu {
    display: block;
  }
}
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item-has-children" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#page1/">Page 1</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">subpage 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#page2">Page 2</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">subpage 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children" aria-expanded="false"><a href="#page3">Page 3</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="#">subpage 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>




[Just an opinion, this comment may be deleted later] The code looks too complicated for such a thing. A re-implementation can help you understand the issues and have a cleaner result.

window.removeEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', prevFirstClick, true ); You have the wrong event name. DOMContentLoaded should be click, just like in addEventListener.

This is not the case. In both cases add Event and remove Event don't work properly. Please notice that when you resize window their are not fired.

Also, adding a DOMContentLoaded event listener inside a DOMContentLoaded event listener guarantees it will never run; it's too late by that point, the event has already fired

This is weird... the same code on my local machine don't work properly. But here when I run code snippet it's work, what the...?! -.-

Thanks guys, all your comments helped me a lot, they are encouraging!
